# converting a MAC address represented as a string to unit8_t, Arduino

Tags: arduino, data-conversion

I'm currently working on an Arduino sketch, and need a way to convert the following mac address:

const char *ss = "00:1E:C0:04:9F:F3";

into a unit8_t*,  so that I can use it as the argument for the network_set_MAC function below:

/*Sets the MAC address of the device*/
void network_set_MAC(uint8_t* mac);

Any ideas on how to do this within the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Do you need your sketch to be able to convert any MAC address it receives at runtime? Or is it a one-off MAC address which you're hard-coding into your sketch?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield It's a one-off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically converting a text-representation to a machine-readable representation is harder than it looks. It would require some careful parsing.

Since you're hard-coding the MAC address into your sketch though, you don't need to worry about that. You can simply write it as an array of hexadecimal literals:

```
uint8_t mac[] = {0x00, 0x1E, 0xC0, 0x04, 0x9F, 0xF3};
```

In C++, an array type will happily decay to a pointer, so you should be able to pass it directly to your function like this:

```
network_set_MAC(mac);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is very late but here is the one option

```
uint8_t mac[6];
char *macAddress="84:0D:8E:AA:5B:44";
sscanf(macAddress, "%X:%X:%X:%X:%X:%X", &mac[0], &mac[1], &mac[2], &mac[3], &mac[4], &mac[5]);
```